# Post html special characters in their entity form

Tags: php, html

Basically, how can I make this `&lt;` stay like this `&lt;` when I'm posting it into a div.
And keep it from turning into this `<`

Also, will this work on html tags such as these `<h2><a>` as well?

Basically posting it anywhere onto the website. I'm trying to make an edit button. at the moment the source code looks something like this

```
<p>&lt;?php echo &quot;php&quot;; ?&gt;</p>
```

How can I post this to the source code of my text editor(on the website) So that it will look like this

```
 <?php echo "php"; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "posting it into a div"?

Comment: Try `&amp;lt;` (no joke)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `&lt;` to be displayed as `&lt;` in a browser, it has to be converted to `&amp;lt;` first (`&amp;` is the HTML entity for the & sign). In PHP you can do that using `htmlentities()`:

```
echo htmlentities('The HTML entity for < is &lt;');
// Equivalent to:
echo 'The HTML entity for &lt; is &amp;lt;';
```